# Importing System.Linq solves "Class cannot be indexed" error

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have the following code which is failing to compile:

```
Dim ContentSent As HashSet(Of String) = New HashSet(Of String)(SubscriberContent.ContentIdSent.Split(","))
content = New Content
' The next line causes causing the error
content = contentCollection.Find(Function(x) x.CntId = Convert.ToInt32(ContentSent(0)))
```

The error it gets is:

> Class cannot be indexed because it has no default property

That makes sense.  The weird thing is, when I import `System.Linq` the compilation error disappears.

For a more simple example, this code gets the error:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic

Module MyModule
    Public Sub Main()
        Dim x As IEnumerable(Of Integer) = {0, 1, 2, 3}
        Dim item As Integer = x(3) ' Gets error on this line
        Console.WriteLine(item)
    End Sub
End Module
```

But this works:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Linq  ' This is the only difference!

Module MyModule
    Public Sub Main()
        Dim x As IEnumerable(Of Integer) = {0, 1, 2, 3}
        Dim item As Integer = x(3) 
        Console.WriteLine(item)  ' Outputs "3"
    End Sub
End Module
```

Why does importing the `System.Linq` namespace solve that particular error?  It doesn't seem like it should.

Comment: This is not compilable. Please post a [Short Self Contained Correct Example](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: DownVoters Care to state the reason ?

Comment: I did state my reason. There isn't nearly enough here to debug your code except psychically. We don't have definitions for ANY of your classes. You were very lucky TnTinMn was psychic enough to solve your problem.

Comment: @Aron thanks for your comment as i didn't think there is need for defining my classes as i have stated the line causing the error  which is related to an index. I thought it was clear but maybe i should have emphasized on ContentSent(0) and not the whole line.

Comment: With VB.net it's difficult to know what is a function call or a indexer. No where do you make that clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably the offending item is: `ContentSent(0)`

It appears that once you Import System.Linq, that VB automatically uses the extension method ElementAtOrDefault as a "pseudo default" indexer for ContentSent.

You can see this for yourself, if you backspace over the index and observe the Intellisense display.

---

@StevenDoggart's comment prompted me to revisit this issue.  This behavior by VB is specified in the [Visual Basic Language Specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/reference/language-specification/).

This particular VB feature is known as the [Default Query Indexer](https://github.com/dotnet/vblang/blob/master/spec/expressions.md#default-query-indexer).

> Default Query Indexer
>
> Every queryable collection type whose element type is T and does not
>   already have a default property is considered to have a default
>   property of the following general form:
>
> ```
> Public ReadOnly Default Property Item(index As Integer) As T
>     Get
>         Return Me.ElementAtOrDefault(index)
>     End Get
> End Property
> ```
>
> The default property can only be referred to using the default
>   property access syntax; the default property cannot be referred to by
>   name. For example:
>
> ```
> Dim customers As IEnumerable(Of Customer) = ...
> Dim customerThree = customers(2)
>
> ' Error, no such property
> Dim customerFour = customers.Item(4)
> ```
>
> If the collection type does not have an ElementAtOrDefault member, a
>   compile-time error will occur.

Comment: It's worth noting that this is a VB.NET specific behavior.  It's not inherent to .NET or LINQ.  For instance, in C#, you still can't access an `IEnumerable<T>` via an indexer (e.g. `ContentSent[0]`), even if `System.Linq` is imported.

Comment: @StevenDoggart, yes it is a VB language feature.  See my edit for more info.